# Save information about only one image

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Hi everyone i have 1 simple problem but i don't know how to solve it. So i'v retrieve images dynamically from flickr and i want to save to db photo id, url and album title, this is i'm already achieve but when i click on image it save all images on my page. So here is my View

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // set to  url main parameter apikey and userid for retrieve photosets with all additional info
    var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=715a9548b42114d69859975d717210cd&user_id=@ViewBag.uId&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
        $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function (idx, item) {

            var photosetid = item.id;
            var photosurl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=e6be1bfdf4294482904dce01ac431615&photoset_id=' + photosetid + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=?';

            //  build a new url for each photoset
            $('#gallery').append('<h3 class="echo" id="' + idx + '" >' + item.title._content + '</h3><ul class="gallery photos grp' + idx + '"></ul>');

            $.getJSON(photosurl, function (data) {
                $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (photoNum, photo) {
                    var photoid = photo.id;
                    var secret = photo.secret;
                    var server = photo.server;
                    var farm = photo.farm;
                    var photo_url = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_s.jpg';
                    var photo_urlm = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_m.jpg';
                    $('.photos.grp' + idx).append('<li><a class="example" data-toggle="tooltip" id="'+photo.id+'"  title="' + photo.title + '"  href="#"><img data-album="'+item.title._content+'" class="save" id="'+photoid+'" title="'+photo.title+'" src="' + photo_url + '" /></a></li>');
                    //  $('.photos.grp' + idx).css('display','none');
                      var id = 'h3#' + idx;
                    $('#gallery').on('click', id, function() {
                        $(this).next('photos.grp' + idx).toggle();
                    });

                    $('.photos').css('list-style-type', 'none');

                    $('.example').tooltip(
                    {
                        animation: true,
                    });
                    // i'm little confused about correct writing of this request, it's save all img's url's, title and etc. beginig from that iamge wath you clicked
                    // instead of saving only one...
                    $('.save').click(function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "POST",
                            url: '@Url.Action("Save","Home")',
                            data: { id: photoid, albumName: item.title._content, photoUrl: photo_url },
                            success: function() {
                                $('#result').text('Image has been saved');
                                var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                                    $('#result').empty();
                                }, 3000);
                            },
                    });
                    });
                });


            });
        });

    });


});
```

controller

```
  public ActionResult Save()
    {
        return View("Index");
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Save(Favourite model)
    {
        db.Favourites.Add(model);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return View("Index");
    }
```

and simple model

```
  public class Favourite
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string photoUrl { get; set; }
    public string albumName { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're using `$.each()` to loop through all the images and you're calling a save post on each loop.  It's not designed how you want it.

You need to redefine the variables being fed to the post object, and it can be easily done by capturing the data from the `<img>` tag that you've already loaded.

What your code is doing is applying a `.click()` event for each image it loops through and applying it to the `.save` link.  That's why it saves all images when you click it.  You have to individualize the click, and by that I mean you have to first target only THIS `<img>` (not all), and you have to pull the parameters for saving the image from the attributes you have defined in the `<img>` tag, instead of using the variables being gathered in the each function.

You can view this modified code for an idea of how it's done:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // set to  url main parameter apikey and userid for retrieve photosets with all additional info
        var url = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getList&api_key=715a9548b42114d69859975d717210cd&user_id=@ViewBag.uId&format=json&jsoncallback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
            $.each(data.photosets.photoset, function (idx, item) {

                var photosetid = item.id;
                var photosurl = 'https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?&method=flickr.photosets.getPhotos&api_key=e6be1bfdf4294482904dce01ac431615&photoset_id=' + photosetid + '&media=photos&format=json&jsoncallback=?&per_page=?';

                //  build a new url for each photoset

                $("<h3/>")
                    .addClass("echo")
                    .attr("id",idx)
                    .html(item.title._content)
                    .after("<ul class='gallery photos grp" + idx + "'></ul>");
                    .click(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).next("ul.photos").toggle();
                    })
                    .appendTo("#gallery");

                $.getJSON(photosurl, function (data) {
                    $.each(data.photoset.photo, function (photoNum, photo) {
                        var photoid = photo.id;
                        var secret = photo.secret;
                        var server = photo.server;
                        var farm = photo.farm;
                        var photo_url = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_s.jpg';
                        var photo_urlm = 'http://farm' + farm + '.static.flickr.com/' + server + '/' + photoid + '_' + secret + '_m.jpg';



                        var $img = $("<img/>")
                            .data("album",item.title._content)
                            .addClass("save")
                            .attr("id",photoid)
                            .attr("title",photo.title)
                            .attr("src",photo_url);

                        var $link = $("<a/>")
                            .addClass("example")
                            .data("toggle","tooltip")
                            .attr("id",photo.id)
                            .attr("title",photo.title)
                            .attr("href","#")
                            .tooltip({animation: true})
                            .click(function (e) {
                                    e.preventDefault();
                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: '@Url.Action("Save","Home")',
                                        data: { id: photo.id, albumName: photo.title, photoUrl: photo_url },
                                        success: function() {
                                            $('#result').text('Image has been saved');
                                            var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
                                                $('#result').empty();
                                            }, 3000);
                                        },
                                    });
                                });

                        var $li = $("<li/>");

                        var $li.append( $link.append( $img ) );

                        $('.photos.grp' + idx)
                            .append( $li )
                            .css('list-style-type', 'none');


                    });


                });
            });

        });


    });
```